# How to initialize data.frame with column of type POSIXct?

Tags: r, dataframe, posixct

I can initialize a data.frame via

```
df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=character())
```

But how do I define a column of type POSIXct?

```
df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=character(), c=POSIXct())
```

won't work.

Comment: Maybe `df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=character(), c=as.POSIXct(character()))` does what you want?

Comment: @konvas Thanks, that was, what I was looking for. You can write it as answer and I'll give you the reward.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try

```
df <- data.frame(a=numeric(), b=character(), c=as.POSIXct(character()))
```

Similarly, you can create a `POSIXct` column of `NA`s in a data frame with > 0 rows by creating a new column with `as.POSIXct(NA)`.

Answer (score 1):

An additional tip to the above initialization:  If you begin rbind() activities to add rows to this empty data frame, you may encounter an error like the following if you follow this pattern:

```
oneDF <- rbind(oneDF,twoDF,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
Error in as.POSIXct.default(value) :
  do not know how to convert 'value' to class "POSIXct"
```

I finally discovered that removing the stringsAsFactors=FALSE allowed for the POSIXct value (both integer time and time zone) to transfer to the target DF.

```
oneDF <- rbind(oneDF,twoDF)
```

examining the result:

```
unclass(oneDF$mytime)
[1] 1282089600
attr(,"tzone")
[1] "GMT"
```